# How to manage dual or more screen in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a python program that can be able to detect the number of screens connected my computer and their characteristics. 
The goal is to be able to select the screen where I project the image.
I have tried with the command "winfo" of Tk  but I just find information about the principal screen.
Thank-you  in advance for you help

Comment: you need to add more info to your question: what OS are you on? What do you mean wit h"where I project the image"?

Comment: I use Mac OS HighSierra personally but the final app will be on windows.

Comment: For the app, I want to use two screens: one for the settings and the other one use to display the image.